# How can I stop my app from logging people out of their session in Safari?

Tags: macos, cookies, nsurlconnection

My command line testing tool, which uses `NSURLConnection`, is interfering with Safari's cookies. How do I stop this from happening?

Here's what I'm seeing:

1. I log into the web site in Safari.
2. I run my command line based sync tool.
3. The sync tool logs in, and gets several pages of data. For each request, the cookie rolls over. (The sync tool does not log out.)
4. I return to Safari and click a link. The link returns me to the login screen.

If I skip step 2-3, the link in Safari works correctly. My tool is clearly the cause of this.

I'm creating my connections like this:

```
_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request
                                              delegate: self
                                      startImmediately: NO];
```

I'm not doing anything explicitly to the cookies, but just letting the default code handle them.

I'm not sure what's really happening here. If Safari and my app really **shared** the cookies, wouldn't Safari's copy of the cookie also be rolled over? While weird behaviour, everything would work and I wouldn't even know what was happening. This is something else.

Anyway, how can I stop my command line tool from logging people out of their session in Safari?

Comment: You could try `-[NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO]` to turn off default cookie behavior, and then manage them yourself behind the scenes (by reading them from responses and inserting them back into the correct subsequent requests). This should prevent it from touching Safari's cookie store.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, Kevin. It's what I'm currently doing in other apps (I'd forgotten), and what I hope to avoid, but it's probably the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the right approach here is turning off default cookie handling entirely, so it doesn't touch the shared store. You can use `-[NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO]` to disable the default behavior, then read the cookie headers out of the responses, store them yourself, and insert them back into subsequent URL requests as appropriate.